# Spark Standalone java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have Spark Standalone application on 64GB ram server. The amount of data I want to process is much more than the amount of ram I can afford.

I'm reading a huge amount of data into one big table and trying to do self-join on it. Pseudo-code looks like this:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("huge_table.parquet")
val df2 = df.select(...).withColumn(...) // some data manipulations
df.as("df1").join(df2.as("df2"), $"df1.store_name" == $"df2.store_name" && $"df1.city_id" === $"df2.city_id")
```

My executor settings look like this `--driver-memory 8g --executor-memory 32g`.

`spark-defaults.conf`:

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -XX:+UseG1GC
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+UseG1GC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

The problem is that no matter what I do, I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeSorterSpillReader.<init>(UnsafeSorterSpillReader.java:53)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeSorterSpillWriter.getReader(UnsafeSorterSpillWriter.java:150)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.getSortedIterator(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:472)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:142)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowExec$$anonfun$14$$anon$1.fetchNextRow(WindowExec.scala:301)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowExec$$anonfun$14$$anon$1.<init>(WindowExec.scala:310)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowExec$$anonfun$14.apply(WindowExec.scala:290)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowExec$$anonfun$14.apply(WindowExec.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
```

I've tried to persist tables before data manipulations, tried `df.persist(org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)`

I know I don't have enough resources to process data efficiently, but what can I do to make process finish, no matter how long does it take.

**UPDATE**

df

```
+----+--------------+---------+
| ID |  store_name  | city_id |
+----+--------------+---------+
|  1 | Apple ...    |      22 |
|  2 | Apple ...    |      33 |
|  3 | Apple ...    |      44 |
+----+--------------+---------+
```

df2

```
+----+--------------+---------+---------+-------------+
| ID |  store_name  | city_id | sale_id | sale_amount |
+----+--------------+---------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | Apple ...    |      33 |       1 | $30         |
|  2 | Apple ...    |      44 |       2 | $50         |
|  3 | Apple ...    |      44 |       3 | $50         |
|  4 | Apple ...    |      44 |       4 | $50         |
|  5 | Apple ...    |      44 |       5 | $40         |
+----+--------------+---------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: It seems like a cartesian join for me. Isn't it ?

Comment: @eliasah not sure if it's cartesian join, but tables have a different amount of rows and multiple join conditions. sometimes result of joining rows if null.

Comment: There is not much we can help you with with the current question details, so I would broadly suggest to try setting spark.sql.shuffle.partitions to 2001. Apache Spark uses a different data structure for shuffle book-keeping when the number of partitions is > 2000 https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4be33758354e1f95fd1d82a5482f3f00218e8c91/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/MapStatus.scala#L52

Comment: Try repartitioning like I said. It's in fact a Cartesian join

Comment: @eliasah same problem :(

Comment: You need definitely more RAM then

Comment: @eliasah thank you! I will.